# MATLAB function for recognition of single character image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, matlab-cvst

I need to implement a simple OCR to convert some characters in one line into text in matlab. so far I've done noise reduction, thresholding and segmentation and I get images like this:
[image]

Now all I need is to classify this character. is there any matlab function to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `ocr` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.